SQL more purchases
I need to populate the boolean field "oldClient" with true if the subscriber has made other purchases in the last 1 year apart from the one in the last 2 days. I used the query
CASE WHEN (PurchaseDate >= convert(date,getDate()-360) AND PurchaseDate  < convert(date,getDate()-2))
THEN 'true'
ELSE 'false'
END AS oldClient
but the field is populated wrongly.
Thanks

I believe you want a boolean called 'oldClient' to have the value = 'true' if the subscriber has made a purchase within the last two days and another purchase before that but not older than 360 days.
Try this logic:
when 
sum(case when PurchaseDate >= dateadd(d, -2, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when PurchaseDate >= dateadd(d, -360, getdate()) and PurchaseDate < dateadd(d, -2, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
then 'true'
else 'false'
end as oldClient

It uses sums to count the number of purchases within the last two days and within the last 360 days (not incl. last two days)
